# How to prevent Angular1.0 select (dropdown) extra white space?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I am working on an AngularJS 1.0 application and facing an issue with Angular Select.

Just Copying a dummy code:

```
<select ng-model ="data.state" ng-options="data.states">
```

Select

Here, it's listing states of a country and passing a default data as ng-model.

I need to show a text "Select" if default  is not matching with the data source.

But it's not working as expected and it's showing an extra empty space instead of select.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give us the working snippet? I guess the problem is object does not assigned clearly.

Comment: You should check your states array.. it should have space. since the select options are based on the array.

Comment: State array is having an empty string.

FYI: Select is there in listed data but it is not being select as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I need to show a text "Select" if default is not matching with the data source." In this case your `data.state` may be empty (ie "") case. You may be expecting some logic like this:

```
<label>States : </label>
  <select ng-model ="data.state" ng-options="data for data in data.states" >
    <option value="" selected hidden >SELECT</option> 
    <!--Removes the Empty space and shows "SELECT" as pre-populated by default in the drop-down. -->
  </select>
<br>Selected State : {{data.state}}
```

Empty space appears as a placeholder offered by Angular to hold text like `"Select an option"` or `"Choose a best answer"`. You can override this using the `<option value="" selected hidden >Select</option>` which won't appear in the selected drop down options list as it is `hidden`.

If you wish to have the select appear as an option for user to choose in order if the field can be remained empty and is not mandatory you can use the following code instead:

```
 <option value="" selected >SELECT</option>
```

In controller expecting the data as:

```
 // $scope.data.state = something that is returned from some API response
 $scope.data = {
  states: [
    "Kerala",
    "Karnataka",
    "Andhra",
    "Haryana"
  ]
}
```

Checkout the [JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nithin_krishnan/bt360f15/) for working sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model ="data.state" ng-options="data.states">
```

make use of track by in ng-repeat. track by $index or id if any